# Repeated verification code popup when I use the app "Music" with WiFi on

Tags: iphone, music.app

I have an iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3.3 and I am experiencing a strange situation. Whenever I listen to my own music, through the Music app, and the WiFi is on, I have a verification code popup from a remote server.
I am *almost* sure about the reason: the device is trying - through the Internet connection - to update the mp3 tags (artists, covers, etc...) of my collection. I suspect this because:

1. The request arrives from Milan (Italy), a city at almost 100 KM from my position and in which Apple servers could reside.
2. If I turn WiFi off, those requests stop appearing.
3. If I turn the traffic data on, with the option "Use traffic data to update music tags" (I hope to having translated it almost correctly because I don't have the English language activated), the requests appear again; otherwise, if I uncheck that option, they do not appear.

By the way, it should not happen. The device should update the collection in a silent way, with no two-factor authentication requests from an official server (whenever I close one of them, the next one appears after some seconds). This is quite annoying. Plus, it seems that there's no way to deactivate tags updating when the WiFi is on.

If someone could shed some light it would be great. Thanks.

For clarification:

[image]

Translation: Your Apple ID is being used for access to a device near Milan, Lombardy

**EDIT**: Thinking about that more after posting it, I have the feeling that the server in Milan (which should be an official Apple server that updates data on my device) is not "certified" in a certain way, so the iPhone asks for verifying it in a first place. Don't know if it makes sense, It's my first Apple device and I do not know certain logic very well.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. Pairing requests come via Bluetooth, not WiFi, so would be limited to devices within approx 10m or so, & come from devices such as headsets, speakers etc, not from servers over the internet.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thank you, and sorry for the confusion: in fact, I said "pairing requests", but I meant two-factor authentication. I have updated my question.

Comment: WHere is your network supplier based?

Comment: @Mark: don't know exactly (I just know that's an Italian company), but the same popup (with the same location) appears everywhere I go: at home, with the office network, at friends' home, at the gym...all these places have a certain distance from each other, and different Internet providers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say with absolute certainly but the best guess would be that, so long as these requests/confirmations always appear within a few seconds/minutes of you activating the function, that it's simply not accurately logging your location.

I live in London & most times these requests appear to come from an area within 5 miles of where I live.
However, when I visit my relatives in Tenerife, all requests of this type appear to originate in Madrid, some 2000km away.
I've simply got used to the idea that this always happens.

Comment: Thank you again, Tetsujiin. By the way, I have to say that I do not "activate" any function (I just open the app Music and start playing a track). Moreover, I think that Milan is the position of the remote server, and not a misinterpreted location of mine: _all_ the functionalities (photo tagging, Maps, Safari, weather forecast, etc...) report my exact position (in the order of meters...).

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー Thoise apps uise GPS but some only seem to use the address of the network provider - depends on what the provider has moved arounbd internally